# PowerShell 2.0 current script function should override module one

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Let's say there is:

*Main script file:*

```
function Test
{
   Write-Host "Hello from sctipt"
}

Import-Module SomeModule.psm1

Test
```

*SomeModule.psm1 content:*

```
function Test
 {
    Write-Host "Hello from module"
 }
```

If I run the main script - the output would be "Hello from script". This module contains a lot of functions that add new functionality. However, in a single case I need to be able main script function to override module one.

In the documentation it is listed, that one can use fully qualified function names, including the module name to call the right function instance. However I can not find how to make referrence to the local one.

Have someone solved such problem? The issue is also that I restricted to run *PowerShell 2.0*, which does not have -NoClobber option while importing the module.

Comment: Try reversing the order (import the module before defining the function).

Comment: As Bill stated, your order is wrong.  The latest, lowest-scope option will be used, in this case after the import, is the module definition.